# How to fix 'A non well formed numeric value encountered' error in laravel?

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-8

I got this error today, with no reason, because my laravel application working fine.

I have this code for my price in my blade :

```
<li>
    @php
        $totalPrice = Cart::all()->sum(function ($cart){
              return (int) $cart['product']->price * (int) $cart['quantity'];
        })
    @endphp
    <span>Total price : </span><span> {{ number_format((float)$totalPrice) }}</span>
</li>
```

But i have this error :

```
A non well formed numeric value encountered
```

In this line :

```
return (int) $cart['product']->price * (int) $cart['quantity'];
```

Before this i got this error for my `number_format`, after searching about it, I find out who I have to use `number_format((float)$price)` and it solved, but I don't know how can I fix this one ?!

Comment: if you dump the `$cart['product']->price` and `$cart['quantity']` variables, do you get a number back? either in string or int

Comment: @PatricNox it's return string for me

Comment: can you show us the return value?

Comment: string(8) "14750000", ' 14750000 ' is the price

Comment: Is that the return value from **just** one of the variables? If so, then you get the error due to the comma.

Comment: @Waltun check my answer below, and comment if that does not work for you for some reason?

Comment: @PatricNox $cart['product']->price is string but  $cart['quantity'] is integer

Comment: You can wrap your calculation in a try/catch to see the values causing the error:

`try { return (int) $cart['product']->price * (int) $cart['quantity']; } catch (\Throwable) { dd($cart['product']->price, $cart['quantity']); }`

Answer (score 0):

Why not use:

```
floatval(number_format($totalPrice)));
```

Which will return `float`

And  `return (int) $cart['product']->price * (int) $cart['quantity'];`
should be:

```
return floatval($cart['product']->price * $cart['quantity']);

// or if you need that to be an integer:
return intval($cart['product']->price * $cart['quantity']);
```

Comment: Will still fail if the variable, as I guess it does, contains a comma or likewise.

Comment: How would you get a comma multiplying 2 `int`s ?

Comment: I have this error : Call to undefined function floatvalat()

Comment: you have misspelled `floatval` :)

Comment: still i have non well formed error, the error belongs to this line : return ((int) $cart['product']->price * (int) $cart['quantity']) +  $post_price ;

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem :))

The codes don't have any problem, In Admin Panel for add new delivery type, in price field I have to just write the price like : 20, not 20 Dollar

Because price filed is just integer, not integer and string :))))

Thanks for your answers <3